# Performance issue in Finite difference method

Tags: c, performance, loops, multidimensional-array

I wrote a piece of C code that uses finite difference method to estimate values. This is an averaging method. I profiled the code and found that one `iterate()` function is the slowest.

```
void iterate(double data[][ARRAY_SIZE], int nx, int ny, int dx, int dy)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < nx; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < ny; ++j)
        {
            if (i % (dx + 1) == 0 && j % (dy + 1) == 0)
                continue;
            else if (i == 0 && 0 < j && j < ny)
                data[i][j] = (data[i][j - 1] + data[i][j + 1] + data[i + 1][j]) / 3;
            else if (j == 0 && 0 < i && i < nx)
                data[i][j] = (data[i - 1][j] + data[i + 1][j] + data[i][j + 1]) / 3;
            else if (i == nx - 1 && 0 < j && j < ny)
                data[i][j] = (data[i][j - 1] + data[i][j + 1] + data[i - 1][j]) / 3;
            else if (j == ny - 1 && 0 < i && i < nx)
                data[i][j] = (data[i - 1][j] + data[i + 1][j] + data[i][j - 1]) / 3;
            else
                data[i][j] = (data[i - 1][j] + data[i + 1][j] + data[i][j - 1] + data[i][j + 1]) / 4;
        }
    }
}
```

This loop runs slow, and I am not sure what I am missing here that makes it slow. Is there a better way of doing the same?

2000 iterations with a `400x400` `double` array takes

```
real    0m1.950s
user    0m1.940s
sys 0m0.004s
```

Comment: Can you give us a typical set of inputs and how long it takes to run for that?

Comment: Are you compiling with `-O3` ?

Comment: Yes, I compiled with `Ofast` as well as `O3`

Comment: You probably want to handle at least some of the edge cases outside the inner loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some ideas:

1. It appears that `ny` must equal `ARRAY_SIZE`.  You may as well omit it as a parameter and just use the compile-time constant.
2. All the if/else clauses except the final one are only applicable to a specific row or column.  So hoist them out.  For example you can process the first row and column as 1D loops before doing the entire matrix outside the edges, then finally process the rightmost column and bottom row.

In the end, your core loop should be more like this:

```
for (int i = 1; i < nx - 1; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 1; j < ARRAY_SIZE - 1; ++j)
    {
        data[i][j] = (data[i - 1][j] + data[i + 1][j] + data[i][j - 1] + data[i][j + 1]) / 4;
    }
}
```

Comment: Interchanging the order of `j` and `i` results in `2.269s`

Comment: Iterate outer dimension first, then inner dimension. The order of his for loops was correct, but the rest of your tips are good.

Comment: @cmaster: I removed that one, thanks for pointing out that I had it wrong.

Comment: Well, I followed your tip and guess what.. the same simulation takes `1.252s`

Answer (score 1):

Consider this implementation:

```
void iterate(double data[][ARRAY_SIZE], int nx, int ny, int dx, int dy)
{
    // because nx - 1 and ny - 1 are used
    nx--;
    ny--;
    // because dx + 1 and dy + 1 are used
    dx++;
    dy++;

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    // case i == 0 && 0 < j && j < ny
    for (j = 1; j < ny; ++j)
    {
        if (j % dy)
            data[0][j] = (data[i][j - 1] + data[i][j + 1] + data[i + 1][j]) / 3.0;
    }

    j = 0;

    // case j == 0 && 0 < i && i < nx
    for (i = 1; i < nx; ++i)
    {
        if (i % dx)
            data[i][0] = (data[i - 1][j] + data[i + 1][j] + data[i][j + 1]) / 3.0;
    }

    // default case
    for (i = 1; i < nx; ++i)
    {
        for (j = 1; j < ny; ++j)
        {
            if (i % dx || j % dy)
                data[i][j] = (data[i - 1][j] + data[i + 1][j] + data[i][j - 1] + data[i][j + 1]) * 0.25;
        }
    }

    // case i == nx && 0 < j && j < ny
    for (j = 1; j < ny; ++j)
    {
        if (nx % dx || j % dy)
            data[nx][j] = (data[i][j - 1] + data[i][j + 1] + data[i - 1][j]) / 3.0;
    }

    // case j == ny && 0 < i && i < nx
    for (i = 1; i < nx; ++i)
    {
        if (ny % dy || i % dx)
            data[i][ny] = (data[i - 1][j] + data[i + 1][j] + data[i][j - 1]) / 3.0;
    }
}
```

The main three points are:

1. reduce the amount of operations in the inner loop for the double for-loop
2. reduce the amount of trivial operations by doing them only once
3. don't mix data types and force coercion (use `/ 3.0` and `* 0.25`)

The only thing in my code not explained is that `i % dx || j % dy` is equal to `!(i % dx == 0 && j % dy == 0)`.

Comment: I pretty much implemented the same here, Thanks. https://gist.github.com/nishanthkarthik/bf67e08273bf1afd91ae9e825fc17ba8

Comment: Oh, some good points. I can add even more optimization. Let me try to get you under one second ;)

Comment: @KarthikNishanth one thing I notice in your code: are you assuming `(nx - 1) % (dx + 1) != 0` and same for `ny` / `dy`?

Comment: I updated my code with your suggestions, got *way* better results (looks better when visualized), and you helped me save `1s`